# location of .arangosh.rc in windows

Tags: arangodb

I try to create a .arangosh.rc file with the timed-function as documented in
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/tools/arangodb-shell/details/#shell-configuration

Unfortunately, I did not find any hint, in which concrete directory I shall store the .rc file. I also tried to start arangosh with the --configuration,  but this throws an error. When starting arangosh with --javascript.execute, it *only* executes the javascript and directly finishes afterwards.

Can anybody provide me a hint, please?

Answer (score 1):

> arangosh will look for a user-defined startup script named .arangosh.rc in the user's home directory on startup. If the file is present arangosh will execute the contents of this file inside the global scope.

On Linux, the directory name convention for the home directory is `/home/<linux-user-name>`

The location of the home directory on Windows may vary depending on settings. On the Windows I have access to, the Windows explorer shows a localized name of the directory (`C:\Benutzer\<windows-user-name>`) even though the file system's actual directory name is `C:\Users\<windows-user-name>`. ArangoDB will determine the home directory on Windows by peeking into the enviroment variables `%HOMEDRIVE%` and `%HOMEPATH%`.

Putting the `.arangosh.rc` file into `C:\Users\<windows-user-name>` worked for me when I tried. I put the `timed` function into it and could use it in arangosh afterwards.

If it doesn't work for you, could you post which Windows version you're using (and if possible also the name of the home directory so we can try to reproduce)? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a company-administrated PC, so there are several user-home-directories which possibly could be used. I tried some of them, but non of them worked. And even if: in contrast to unix, the working-directory for Arango projects on Windows systemes often is completely somewhere else, so: would it be possible to provide a startup parameter (something like "--path-to-rc")? this would make the system much more flexible ...

Comment: can you check the contents of the `%HOMEPATH% and `%HOMEDRIVE%` enviroment variables in an MS-DOS prompt with the current user? This should reveal the components of the home directory that will be used by ArangoDB.

Comment: Yes, there are such env variables. Interestingly they are not in the windows user environment settings ... but they are here when asking it's echo in a cmd prompt. And surprisingly they point to a location which I never would have expected (I never use it normally). The good thing is, after storing the .arangosh.rc there, it works. Fine!
--> THANKS AGAIN FOR YOUR HELPFUL ANSWER.
--> Still better would be to be able to decide where to put such stuff, but ... well, that's of course not the most important thing in the world :-)